# Storing resource files in different projects in same solution

Tags: asp.net, class, resources, file, project

I have a project where I need different versions of the same site.

I need to accomplish this by having different versions of the same resource files.

I would like to store the different versions of the same resource files in seperate projects in the same solution.  Then choose which project of resource files to use when I publish or compile.

I've been searching the net everywhere and my deadline is coming up.

If someone know the solution to this I would be very greatful.

Comment: I posted this a long time ago.  But the solution I had used was to add a prefix to the resource file, then overide the GetGlobalResourceObject function to get the resource file according to prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I think, such thing is not possible, as , AFAIK resource files are project specific. But SO guru's will definitely give you some good idea. 
I can suggest you a work around, instead of creating a resource file , create a separate project in your solution named MyProject.AppName.Common, add a class file there and in that class file write your required constants that can be shared among each and every project in the solution. 
I hope you like the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i will tru this.